# Add pause function to slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very nice slider script here and already figured out to get bullets underneath it, but i just want to know.. is it possible to add some simple lines to it so that the image is pausing/on hold while on mouse over?

Here is my code now:

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#slideshow div:gt(0)").hide();

        var index;
        index = 0;
        var totalslides;
        totalslides = 2;

        var nextSlide = function () {
            $('#slideshow div').eq(index).fadeOut(1000);
            $('#nav' + index).toggleClass('navselected');
            index++;
            if (index > totalslides - 1) { index = 0; }
            $('#slideshow div').eq(index).fadeIn(3000);
            $('#nav' + index).toggleClass('navselected');
        }

    var nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 7000);

        function nav(selectedSlide) {
            clearInterval(nextSlideTimer);

            $('#slideshow div').eq(index).fadeOut(1000);
            $('#nav' + index).toggleClass('navselected');
            index = selectedSlide;
            $('#slideshow div').eq(index).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#nav' + index).toggleClass('navselected');

            nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 4000);
        }

        $("#nav0").click(function () { nav(0); });
        $("#nav1").click(function () { nav(1); });
    });



</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
#slideshow { position: relative; width: 960px; height: 300px; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);}
#slideshow div { position: absolute; top: 10px ; left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; }  
#slideshow a {display: block;width:960px;height:300px; }    
#slideshow a:hover{background-position: center bottom;}

#slideshownav a.navselected{color:#eb910c;}
#slideshownav {text-align:center; padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:20px;}
#slideshownav a {padding-right:10px;color:#748090;font-size:50px; text-decoration: none; }
#slideshownav a:hover {cursor:pointer;}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>IMAGE 1</div>
    <div>IMAGE 2</div>
</div>
<div id="slideshownav">
    <a id="nav0" class="navselected">&#176;</a>
    <a id="nav1">&#176;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
$('#slideshow').mouseover(function () {
    // Clear the interval.
    clearInterval(nextSlideTimer);
}).mouseout(function () {
    // Start it nextSlide again.
    nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
});
```

Or better, you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (see jQuery docs for demo):

```
$('#slideshow').mouseenter(function () {
    // Clear the interval.
    clearInterval(nextSlideTimer);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    // Start it nextSlide again.
    nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
});
```

The second approach is better because, it doesn't fire much events when you are moving around the inner elements of the parent slider.

Comment: Thanks dude, but as i just replied to Mottie.. jQuery is hit & hope for me. Where to place this, just in front of the last }); ?

Comment: The last one buddy... Add it just before last `});`.

Comment: Thanks dude! Marked it as helpfull.

Comment: No you are ;). One more thing, do you know how to get nicer bullets than &#176; LOL. Probably with CSS.

Comment: Sure... `content: "&whatever;"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside of the document ready function, near the bottom:

```
$('#slideshow').on('mouseover mouseleave', function( event ) {
  if ( event.type === 'mouseover') {
    // stop slideshow timer
    clearInterval(nextSlideTimer);
  } else {
    // add a shorter time delay
    nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 4000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, jQuery is hit & hope for me. Do i have to place this just in front of the last **});** ?

Comment: Yes, below `$("#nav1").click(function () { nav(1); });` and above the `});` is fine.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but yours didnt work, anyhow thanks. Besides it doesn't matter anymore because the one above from Praveen did. So i've been helping out. Thanks both

Comment: Mine probably didn't work if you are using jQuery older than v1.7.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script> -- Here you go, you are right. I will update it immediately ;), forget what i said.